# Is there an inequality or identity for $\det (A + \delta I)$ where $\delta$ is a small number greater than 0?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, determinant

I am trying to remember an identity for $\det (A + \delta I)$ where $\delta$ is small and $\delta \geq 0$. I can't remember the formula, but I am hoping someone can recall something that can help me remember or find the formula (or find a smilar formula).

Comment: I suspect I don't know the formula you're after, but some additional information would be good. Are you looking for a bound for how close $\det(A + \delta I)$ is to $\det(A)$? Or something akin to a Taylor series approximation?

Comment: I have a simple function $f = \det (A  + c I) - c^n$ where $c \geq 0$ and $A$ positive semi-definite, and I am trying to show the function is nonnegative as a step for another result. If $c=0$, then $f \geq 0$. If I replace $c$ with $c + \delta$, I want to show that the function is still nonnegative. I was thinking this identity would help me. Edit: $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix.

Comment: Check out [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/65424/determinant-of-sum-of-positive-definite-matrices), and substitute $B = cI$.

Comment: @user837206 I am familiar with the Minkowski inequality. Thanks for pointing this out! I think I can prove my result using this, but I am sad I didn't think of this before... Based on the answers, I might be able to show the result using another route as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, here's one thing we can do.

Suppose $A$ has eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n$. Then $\det(A) = \prod_{i=1}^n \lambda_i$. Meanwhile, $A+\delta I$ has eigenvalues $\lambda_1 + \delta, \dots, \lambda_n + \delta$. So
$$
   \det(A + \delta I) = \prod_{i=1}^n (\lambda_i + \delta)
$$
and we can try to do something by expanding this product. From each factor $\lambda_i + \delta$ we can pick either the $\lambda_i$ or the $\delta$.

- If we pick the $\lambda_i$ from each factor, we get $\displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^n \lambda_i$ again, which is $\det(A)$.
- If we pick $\delta$ instead of $\lambda_j$ once, and pick $\lambda_i$ everywhere else, we get $\frac{\det(A)}{\lambda_j} \cdot \delta$.
- If $\delta$ is very small, we can ignore all the terms where we picked $\delta$ two or more times.

This gives us
$$
   \det(A + \delta I) = \det(A) + \delta \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\det(A)}{\lambda_j} + O(\delta^2).
$$
Let's try to understand the coefficient of $\delta$. Factoring out $\det(A)$, we get $\frac1{\lambda_1} + \dots + \frac1{\lambda_n}$. These are the eigenvalues of $A^{-1}$, and their sum is the trace! This gives us the approximation
$$
   \det(A + \delta I) = \det(A) + \det(A) \text{tr}(A^{-1})\delta + O(\delta^2).
$$

Comment: Thanks! This isn't what I recall, but works for my problem perfectly.